# Why is this code not copying text from textView?

Tags: android

```
inputText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label",
                        inputText.getText());
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            } else {
                android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                clipboard.setText(inputText.getText());
            }

        }
    });
```

Why does this code not copy text from a textView, it does not show any error but does not work either.

Comment: Post your logcat trace...please..!!!

Comment: `setOnClickListener` for TextView is executing or not?

Comment: It should because i am putting no if else condition in it.

Comment: May be a wild guess but try this `inputText.getText().toString()`